# .Cordova installation error

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am trying to install cordova on my windows 10 laptop but ended up with error

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jk2\npm-debug.log
```

I am connected to home network so no proxy is required. 
I have tried 
npm cache clean but no luck. What else can be checked now?

[[image: Cordova Installation error]]

npm install -g cordova@5.4.1 --verbose gives me below error:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Hm5.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B6zj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your network connection, try to run

```
npm install xxx --verbose
```

to get more info.

I notice `cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80` in your log, are you setting the npm proxy to 127.0.0.1:80?

try to run

```
npm config get proxy
npm config get https-proxy
```

If either is present, run

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

to unset them.

That should solve the problem.

Comment: npm config get proxy
npm config get https-proxy
give me 'null'.
When i execute npm install -g cordova@5.4.1 --verbose
i have attached images in main question.
image1 image2